# After how much time do ground/powdered spices start losing their flavor?

Tags: spices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shelf life of spices](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/70/shelf-life-of-spices)

Suppose I grind the mustard + cumin + pepper seeds and keep them covered in a bowl, after how much time should I expect them to lose their flavor?

Authoritative answers with references to some credible sources will be appreciated.

### EDIT 1:

The packed powdered/ground spices we get in shops don't taste the same as freshly ground. Hence my question.

### EDIT 2:

Info required for spices namely: Cumin, Mustard, pepper.
and Garlic/Ginger too.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Shelf life of spices](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/70) Yes/no?